# Assign values inside a function in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have piece of code, which is not working, and I couldn't manage why. Help please.

```
@Injectable()
export class PersonService {
    private person: Person = new Person();
    ...
    getPerson(name: string): void {
        const url = `${this.personsUrl}/getByName/${name}`;
        this.http.get<Person>(url).toPromise().then(r => {
            console.log(r);  // {id: 1, name: "PersonName"}
            console.log(r.name);  // PersonName
            console.log(r.id);  // 1
            this.person.id = r.id;
            this.person.name = r.name;
        });
        console.log(this.person) // Person {} <--- why?
    }
}
```

I have tried to create a `Person` object inside `then()` function, return it, return `Promise` etc. Tried making copy of documentation, but still it doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic async vs sync issue - you're logging the result before the update has happened. Try appending another `then` and logging out person, or alternatively (assuming your using a modern version of Node) use `async` / `await` e.g.

```
async getPerson(name: string): void {
  ...
  const result = await this.http.get<Person>(url).toPromise();
  // update this.person
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped. But it should return `Promise` instead of `void`.

Comment: @VitaliKuzmin the return type of the function doesn't change, it's still `void`.

Comment: It didn't want to compile without errors, until I changed return type. And IDE was pointing on this problem.

Comment: @VitaliKuzmin ah of course, the use of `async` will dictate a `Promise` is returned. Silly me.